# What's a better way of doing this in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, .net, string, visual-c++, lookup

I don't normally work in Visual C++ but I was wondering what I could do to speed up this logic...and if there's a better way of doing this.

I have a `map<wstring, wstring>` with contents like this:

```
\Device\CdRom0\, E:\
\Device\CdRom1\, F:\
\Device\HarddiskVolume1\,
\Device\HarddiskVolume4\, C:\
\Device\HarddiskVolume5\, D:\
```

And I have a huge list of strings that have the following format:

```
L"\\Device\\HarddiskVolume4\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\FileLocker\\FileLocker\\bin\\Debug\\Test.txt";
```

My whole purpose is to take strings in the above format, use the map as a type of lookup, and convert these strings into the following format (example converting the above string to a drive path):

```
L"C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\FileLocker\\FileLocker\\bin\\Debug\\Test.txt";
```

The way I am doing it currently is as follows (for each string):

```
std::wstring test = ...
for (map<wstring, wstring>::iterator i = volumes.begin(); i != volumes.end(); ++i)
{
    if (test.find((*i).first.c_str()) == 0)
    {
        test = test.replace(0, wcslen((*i).first.c_str()), (*i).second.c_str());
    }
}
```

But there's a lot of strings here, and performance can really take a hit! What are some better ways of performing this lookup and assigning to the string at hand?

Comment: Are the map keys always two path elements separated by slashes?

Comment: I am not sure; on my system yes, but I am not sure if this is always the case because I am using some undocumented Windows APIs to generate these volume strings...I'm not sure what format volume strings are always supposed to be represented in.

Answer (score 1):

If you know there are always exactly two `\` separated terms to match, extract just that part of the string then search for that in the map - or try a hashmap.

If you want to stick to the `map` and same style of logic, you could replace...

```
if (test.find((*i).first.c_str()) == 0)
```

...with `test.compare(0, i->first.size(), i->first)`, so it doesn't try to match at every position along the string.

You could also build a tree of resolution steps:

```
\Device\ ---> Cdrom  --->  0
         |                 1
         |
         ---> HardDiskVolume   ---> 1
                                    4
                                    5
```

The C++ Standard library doesn't provide a convenient container type for modelling this though - if the depth is always 3 you can hardcode a few maps (last numeric one could even be an array), otherwise there's e.g. boost graph.

Comment: It's my bad on the way I phrased the question, and I like your proposal, but I am totally unsure at the moment if volume paths in Windows always take on that type of format. On my system this always seems to be the case, but I am worried that these APIs may produce different results elsewhere.

Comment: @Alexandru: I've go no idea myself... haven't ever used them.  Of course, if you know `Users` is always the first non-volume-path component you could search for that, but that's significantly limiting too.

Answer (score 1):

After a successful replace, use break; to exit the for loop. That will double the performance by eliminating attempts to match other drives. If the frequency of the appearance of the drives is roughly known, ordering the map by that frequency will add to the effectiveness of the break.

Comment: Sometimes I wish they'd let me accept two or more answers on Stack Overflow... :(